# Creating image of CF card produces inconsistent results

Tags: linux, clone, dd, compact-flash

A friend is trying to clone a CF card using the following linux command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=card3.img bs=4M status=progress
```

but each time, it is producing a different image.
The first two cards they have imaged have produced inconsistent results.
What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Is the card currently mounted, maybe things are changing on it

Comment: @Xen2050 He has been unmounting it before each dump.
But just mounting a device shouldn't write to it, should it?

Comment: Mounting itself shouldn't modify device's content, but it enables processes to do so. And there's plenty of stuff running in the background in modern OSes.

Comment: Indeed, but I think it would be considered a bug if an OS wrote to external storage without the users permission.

Comment: Mounting _may_ modify the device's content: it may update the last-mount timestamp on some filesystems, or the root directory's last-access timestamp, or even the journal in some cases.

Comment: What is the story behind two (or more) images? Was this some kind of test? I'm asking because if you consider the card healthy and if you assume nothing has changed, then there's no reason to create a second image. And there were at least two images compared to each other, right? As if your friend suspected they may differ. And one reason to suspect this is when one doubts if the card is healthy. So *maybe* it's not healthy in the first place.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski they are reasonably (10 years?). the image is being made to "preserve" it, so multiple dumps are being done to sort-of "verify" the dumps.

Answer (score 2):

Just mounting with write access (rw) could be writing things, on ext filesystems there's at least the following attributes that are updated:

- Last mounted on
- Mount count
- Last mount time
- And possible files access times that are updated when if files are just read (mount's `noatime` should stop those).
- And a "Last write time" attribute if writing occurs)

> Actually, mounting *without* write access (using mount's `-r` / `-o ro`) might still write to the device, see man mount:
>
> > -r, --read-only
> >
> > Mount the filesystem read-only.  A synonym is -o ro.
> >
> > Note that, depending on the filesystem type, state and kernel behavior, the system **may still write to the device.**  For example, ext3 and ext4 will replay the journal
> >     if the filesystem is dirty.  To prevent this kind of write access, you may want to
> >     mount an ext3 or ext4 filesystem with the **ro,noload** mount options or set the block
> >     device itself to read-only mode, see the `blockdev`(8) command.
>
> And `blockdev` has the `--setro` command, to set a block device as read-only

You could compare the images and see which bytes are different, with `cmp` or something like `vbindiff`. Only a few bytes could be a date or count somewhere (I'm not sure if the attributes are stored as plain text, or encoded somehow).

Or read-only mount two (or more) of the images and compare just the files. Plain `diff` can compare directory trees, but I prefer a gui like `kdiff3`. If the only difference is in the mount count or last mount time it won't show up in the files (different file access times probably won't either).

Or maybe the device or your ram or something else is going bad & reading different bytes here & there.

You could also keep the device unmounted, make an image, then unplug & reconnect the device (still unmounted) and make another image & then compare, they should be the same.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski How would you "deny write access to it before mounting?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Very interesting, I didn't know chmod was all that's needed to ro a device, didn't even know it was possible actually. Have any links to more info? I tried searching & found an inconclusive [Q on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/123615/can-i-change-permissions-on-a-device-with-chmod), and `blockdev --setro` & mount's noload, but mostly drowned in hits for mount ro & "my USB went ro".

Comment: @Xen2050 I was wrong, my tests were not good enough. Now I see `chmod` doesn't prevent access in general. I guess [this is the reason](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/117150/108618). I will delete my comments in few hours.

Comment: @Hiccup See my comment just above. Now I think I mislead you with `chmod`. I'm sorry and I apologize.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Ah well, it did seem almost "too good to be true," at least I learned a little more about mount's sneaky writes & noload & blockdev